# Bootstrap in angular project won't work properly

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use the bootstrap navbar in my angular project. This is how I installed it:

bootstrap + jquery install in the cli:

```
npm install bootstrap jquery --save
```

[image]

`angular-cli.json`:

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

And this is my html:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

If you need something else ask it in the comments.

This is what I get:

[image]

And this is what i expected to be:

[image: e]

Comment: "Won't work"... what doesn't work?

Comment: I get why in most cases but this is pure installation of bootstrap that won't work... but if you want it..

Comment: Updated It. You have the code + what my output is and what i expected to be.

Comment: Did you try the non minified versions of the css and js file?

Comment: @GopakumarGopalan I just tried it but no difference...

Comment: I think the JS part need to be avoided. There is a well explained article here -> https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

I was using bootstrap 3 classes and I imported bootstrap 4. Stupid mistake!

Sorry for the trouble.